# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow' when I test my flask/react app locally(using the procfile command)

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, flask, heroku, gunicorn

Apologies in advance if this is a bad post, new to web dev and stackoverflow.

I am trying to deploy a flask/react.js app with ML models which run on tensorflow; I want to deploy using Heroku w/Python and gunicorn. However, after a successful build, heroku logs show an infinite stream of new workers being created: (the following line increments continuously)

> `[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15999`

Based on [this thread](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1663) this seems to suggest that there are errors in my code, and it is an unfortunate feature of gunicorn that it does not display errors. So, via the "confirm it runs locally" suggestion on the [heroku help site](https://help.heroku.com/HX4L23I4/debugging-deploy-issues-with-gunicorn), I tried to use my Procfile command directly in terminal:

```
GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--graceful-timeout 300 --workers=3" gunicorn wsgi:app
```

This does trace my errors, now; however, I am receiving a ModuleNotFound error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

The full stack trace:

```
[2021-01-20 15:52:24 -0800] [15373] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2021-01-20 15:52:24 -0800] [15373] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (15373)
[2021-01-20 15:52:24 -0800] [15373] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-01-20 15:52:24 -0800] [15374] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15374
[2021-01-20 15:52:24 -0800] [15374] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/michellezhu/produce/cabbage/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from api.main import app
  File "/Users/michellezhu/produce/cabbage/api/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
[2021-01-20 15:52:24 -0800] [15374] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 15374)
[2021-01-20 15:52:24 -0800] [15373] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2021-01-20 15:52:24 -0800] [15373] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I have installed tensorflow 2.4.0 in my virtual environment, which runs fine when I use npm start. Here are my npm package.json commands:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"react-scripts start\" \"npm run start-api\"",
    "start-api": "cd api && env/bin/flask run --no-debugger",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

So, the application works completely fine when I run locally using `npm start` ; but cannot deploy because I don't know how to force my Procfile command to enter the virtual environment and use the pip packages there(including tensorflow). How do I give Heroku/gunicorn access to my virtual environment?(Note: packages within my virtual environment *are* included in my requirements.txt file for when I deploy to Heroku, but since deployment to Heroku only reveals the infinite output of workers re-booting, I can't tell if the errors are a result of tensorflow not importing.)

EDIT: This does not seem to be a virtual environment issue. I downgraded python in order to install all packages outside of the virtual environment, and there is still a ModuleNotFound error for tensorflow(and imutils, and possibly other modules.)

Comment: Did you install required packages using pip install -r requirements.txt.Thanks!